# Apache (XAMPP) cannot start - Port 80 Busy

Tags: apache-2.2, xampp

I cannot start apache on xampp, it says `Busy...`

I have googled this many times and I have tried the following solutions:

1. Skype no longer uses port 80/443
2. Teamviewer no longer uses port 80/443
3. Adding the `NoRun` key to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP` ([Solution found here](http://www.cameroncooke.com/2009/01/25/windows-7-uses-port-80-and-makes-it-impossible-to-install-apache-solution/))

But none of these work, when I visit `localhost` on a browser it will load but just give a blank page, even thought apache isn't started.

I have also run `netstat -ano` on command prompt, I get the following entries using port 80:

`TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4` and
`TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4`

Both are being used by PID 4 which is System when I look it up in task manager.

I have also googled around and seen that this may be caused by VMWare which I have installed but I cannot seem to find a solution for this, can anyone help me with this please. If you need more information then please comment and I will add it.

EDIT:

After running the beta control panel, I get the following in the logs:

`12:57:41  [apache]     Possible problem detected: Port 80 in use by "system"!`
`12:57:41  [apache]     Possible problem detected: Port 443 in use by "vmware-hostd.exe"!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VMware go:

Edit < Preferences < Shared VMs

and **Disable Sharing** (or change the ports if you need the functionality)

Answer (score 2):

Try running [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) from Microsoft sysinternals. It will show you a detailed list of all TCP and UDP endpoints on your system ... It can also report the name of the process that owns the endpoint.

**Update**: If you can't find the program running on that port, it might be a solution to simply change the port of XAMPPs Apache. The directive you need to change is `Listen 80`. Maybe set this to 8000 instead and point your browser to http://localhost:8000/.

Another thing you can try is -if you have VMware installed (Server?) - to check the Windows services panel and try to shut it down there as I suppose it is a service.

Comment: I cannot find anything which is using port 80 in either the local or remote port columns.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you shut down the service, you might not need to change any directive as mentioned above.

Comment: I have changed the port in `httpd.conf` and that seems to be working now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install apache server as a system service (from the apache control panel) - then restart the machine.

You might also need to kill off other processes occupying port::80...